# Sharing data between muliple components - issue due to object references

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, behaviorsubject

I'm implementing a data store service to share data between multiple sibling components. Each components needs to get notified about changes in the data store. The data store does not populate itself, the data needs to be set from a controller.

data.store.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class DocumentIssueStore {

  private _documentIssue: BehaviorSubject<DocumentIssueModel>;

  constructor() {
    this._documentIssue = new BehaviorSubject(null);
  }

  public setValue(newVal: DocumentIssueModel) {
    this._documentIssue.next(cloneDeep(newVal));
  }

  public documentIssue(): Observable<DocumentIssueModel> {
    return this._documentIssue.asObservable();
  }

  public current(): DocumentIssueModel {
    return cloneDeep(this._documentIssue.getValue());
  }
```

In the `ngInit` methods of both components, i subscribe to the data store:

```
// Subscribe to changes in the store
this.storeSubscription = this.documentIssueStore.documentIssue().subscribe(
  (data: DocumentIssueModel) => {
    this.documentIssue = data;
  }
);
```

The problem:
Changing `this.documentIssue` in any component leads to:

- Changing the instance (`this.documentIssue`) in all other components subscribed
- Changing the instance in the store (`this._documentIssue.getValue()`)

The goal:
- Having seperate objects in the components, which can be changed and then send to the store by calling the `setValue` method

Comment: Maybe each subscriber should clone the data if they intend to modify it? This scenario kind of reminds me of a parent component passing an object reference into many child components. Usually the parent wouldn't clone the object for each child - the children would each clone the object to prevent writing to the original. But I am not sure if that's the correct mindset here.

Comment: This is exactly what I need! Thanks!

Comment: mutations to the object in the subject (state transition) should only happen by pushing a new value into the strem (subject.next()), so basically you want immutability in that object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each subscriber could clone the data if they intend to modify it:

```
// Subscribe to changes in the store
this.storeSubscription = this.documentIssueStore.documentIssue().subscribe(
  (data: DocumentIssueModel) => {
    this.documentIssue = cloneDeep(data);
  }
);
```